# 302 redirect, Tomcat behind Apache for hybris

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, mod-jk

I've configured hybris and apache,mod_jk using below blog article.
www.facebook.com/permalink.php?id=317609748375071&story_fbid=680730588729650

hybris is completely running fine on tomcat ports http on 9001 and https on 9002.

one of developer has also configured redirection at hybris level
so any request comes in for http://hot.local:9001/ it gets automatically
redirect to https://hot.local:9002/abc/en.

Now I'm stuck at apache and mod_jk configuration point of view.
I'm not able to setup URL redirection in apache with mod_jk configuration.
Getting below error
[22993:22208] [debug] jk_handler::mod_jk.c 
(2047): Service finished with status=302 for worker=tss1

I'm configuring above stuff on UBUNTU.

Comment: Which operating system you are using? show us your workers and mod_jk.conf settings also will be better to copy paste here the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Opened Port 443 exclusively in ubuntu

2) Include `redirectPort="8443"` in tomcat **siemap.xml**

3) Include below tag in apache2 ssl config

`JkMountCopy On`

Comment: I was using ubuntu 13